# Efficiently find first repeated character in a string without using any additional data structure in one traversal

Tags: java, string

Given a string S. The task is to find the first repeated character in it. We need to find the character that occurs more than once and whose index of second occurrence is smallest. S contains only lowercase letters.

It is giving wrong output for
input-'crg'
output-?
expected -'-1'

Here is my code-

```
private static Character first(String s)
    {
        String str ="";
        char c =(char)-1;
       // int flag=-1;
        char c1='\0';
       
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(str.indexOf(ch)==-1)
            str+=ch;
            else{
                c1=ch;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(s.equals(str))
        return c;
        else
        return c1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(char)-1` is the same as `\uffff`, it will always be printed as `?` because `\uffff` is not a valid unicode character.

Comment: so how do I change it to -1 unicode for returning -1 as output

Comment: There is no such thing as -1 unicode. Since you are returning a boxed character you could return `null` in the case you did not find a repeated character.

Answer (score 0):

Rather trying return `-1` or `char`, you can try to return `index` of String or `-1`, since `-1` is not a valid Unicode character.

Here is a better solution using an int array for counting occurrence in the string, if found 2nd occurrence it will return the index or return `-1`.

```
  static int check(String str){
    int[] cnt= new int[26];
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int v = str.charAt(i)-'a';
      cnt[v]++;
      if(cnt[v] > 1) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Comment: We are not allowed to use any extra space , so tell me any correction in my code@user-Upvote don't say Thanks

Comment: @ShashankSingh `str`,`c1`,`c` also uses extra space and you cann't store `-1` in `char` because it's not valid character in unicode

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private static int first(String s) {
    int[] codePoints = s.codePoints().toArray();
    int max = codePoints.length;
    for (int i = 0, p = 0, n = 0; i < max; p = n, ++i)
        if ((n = codePoints[i]) == p)
            return p;
    return -1;
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(Character.toString(first("絵文字も処理できる")));
```

output